# Innodb doesn't let me update the composite primary key?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm trying to create a history table to store all historical records of its corresponding table

However, when I switch from the **MyISAM** to **InnoDB** (because of the DELETE ON CASCADE) the below query yields the error: `Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`

```
CREATE TABLE tdm_history.BATCH LIKE tdm.BATCH;
ALTER TABLE tdm_history.BATCH MODIFY COLUMN id int NOT NULL,
   DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD action VARCHAR(8) DEFAULT 'insert',
   ADD revision INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   ADD stamp DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   ADD PRIMARY KEY (id, revision);
```

I expect the primary of the `tdm_history.BATCH` from `id` to be changed to the composite primary key of `(id, revision)`.
Note that, the above query works perfectly fine when the engine is set to MyISAM

Comment: 'with an InnoDB table, an AUTO_INCREMENT column must be defined as part of an index' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html - doesn't have to be primary key but if not somewhat devalues auto-increment, if you want (id,revision) to be unique then you could create a unique index.

Comment: @P.Salmon Thank you! I should have checked the documents. Adding an index solved the problem.

Comment: Note that it will behave differently in InnoDB. The auto-increment column will not number `revision` from 1 for each value of `id`. It will just keep incrementing values. InnoDB does not support the per-value auto-increment that MyISAM does.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks for letting me know and I did realize that. Instead of using auto-increment, I re-calculate the ```revision``` for every new insert. Do you have any better way to do that?

Comment: That works unless you have concurrent requests trying to insert. You have a race condition unless you can create a lock to ensure concurrent inserts run serially. This is why it works for MyISAM, which does table-locking by default.

Comment: More on converting from MyISAM to InnoDB, including some discussion on the `AUTO_INCREMENT` issue:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb

Answer (score 0):

Two guesses:

Plan A:  Swap the `MODIFY id` and the `DROP PK`.

Plan B:  Split into two ALTERs.  But I don't know where.  I think the problem is that `ALTER` has not quite let go of the `id`-PK link before you replace the PK.  So, at least, move the `ADD PK` to a second `ALTER`.